# Fill in specific row in pySpark dataframe while adding new columns

Tags: dataframe, pyspark, union

I have a dataframe which consists of 4 rows and more than 20 columns(dates). The dataframe is a table which I read and convert it in a dataframe. The SUM row contains the sum of the values per date.

```
+----+-----+-----+
|PR  |date1|date2|......
+----+-----+-----+
| a  | 30  |  17 |......
| b  | 30  |  12 |......
| SUM| 60  |  29 |......
+----+---+-------+
```

I created this dataframe after the submitting a question here. Since the table is constantly being populated with new data, I want the new data to be added to that dataframe.
I am coding in pySpark and script is the following one:

```
from pyspark.sql import functions as F

if df.filter(df.PR.like('SUM')):
    print("**********")
    print("SUM FOUND")
    df = df.union(df.select(df.where(df.index == 'SUM').select('PR'), *[F.sum(F.col(c)).alias(c) for c in df.columns if c != 'PR']))
else:
    df = df.union(df.select(F.lit("SUM").alias("PR"), *[F.sum(F.col(c)).alias(c) for c in df.columns if c != 'PR']))
```

What I want to achieve is that, for any new date create a new column and fill in the SUM without adding new rows. Unfortunately I am getting the error `AttributeError: 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'index'`
Any help/hint? Should I follow a different approach?

Comment: There are some problems in your code Gerasime 1) the error: 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'index' is caused you have a query df.where(df.index == 'SUM').select('PR') inside another query. A select statement expects one or more params of Column not the results of a previous dataframe as you have now 2) you must find a way to represent the new date data i.e would that be a new array, list or dataframe?

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I think I get what you mean about the query within a query. With regards to your second point,  I'd like to stick with dataframes. (My question is more for my own personal development, because I managed to find a work-around). I will give another try -unless you would like to suggest a different approach!

Comment: The most straight forward approach would be to store the accumulated results into a CSV (since you don't have requirements for a large amount of data) with columns [PR, date1, date2, ....dateN] every time you want to use this you load it into df1 then the new data you save it in a new CSV as well call it df2. Then you join those two producing the desired results!

Comment: Just keep in mind 2 more things 1. if your dataset is really small in the range of KB or MB you shouldn't use Spark at all but you can achieve the same with a simple python program or better with pandas 2. your dataset can not scale horizontally (i.e adding columns) but vertically i.e adding dates which requires you create a new column called date :)

Comment: Then of course you should have 4 columns [date, a, b, SUM] that sounds more reasonable than the structure you have now and it scales more easily